# How To Have A Blog Where Users Can Only Edit Posts For A Limited Time in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, edit

I've made a very simple blog where users can Create, Edit and Delete posts however I want to add functionality where users can only Edit for a limited time (say 3 days). My understanding of Ruby is not strong enough to know how to do this so any help is appreciated.

This is my Notes (my name for Posts) controller

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
    @notes = Note.where(user_id: current_user)
end

def show
end

def new
    @note = current_user.notes.build
end

def create
    @note = current_user.notes.build(note_params)

    if @note.save
        redirect_to @note
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit

end

def update
    if @note.update(note_params)
        redirect_to @note
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @note.destroy
    redirect_to notes_path
end

private

def find_note
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
end

def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :content)
end



end
```

I assume somewhere in the edit method I need to write a rule for restricting the ability to edit posts to only 3 days, using the created_at function somehow? I'm just at a loss as to exactly how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect solution for that is `:before_filter`

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :check_time!, only: [:edit, :update]

    def edit
    end

    def create
    end

    private

    def check_time!
      if Time.now() > @note.created_at + 3.days
        flash[:danger] = 'Out of 3 days'
        redirect_to note_path(@note)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect :)

Comment: Actually I just tested this more deeply, I have a note which is 1 day old and if I change 3.days to 3.hours it will still let me edit. Do you know why this might not be working for me?

Comment: Andrew I can suggest you to wrap (@note.created_at + 3.days) in brakets and check, but any way best practice is use `byebug` and look how will change value